# How to do actions based on template typename checks?

Tags: c++, templates

Just started exploring template feature for one of my task, I need to add some actions based on the typename in the template. Can someone point out what is wrong with this kind of structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    if(std::is_same<T, int>::value)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"foo is: "<<foo<int>()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering:

1. Why this *error* is happening `main.cpp:23:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’` and how to get rid of it?
2. Is there a better way to do specific *actions* based on `typename` provided to the function?

**UPDATE:**

It turned out my program is using below C++17 compiler

**Attempt:**

I tried another approach to handle this case but failed miserably:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U>
T foo()
{
    T t = U;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"foo is: "<<foo<int, 1>()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone can point out what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, even if your `T` is `int`, all the branches still have to compile. So the second return statement causes an error because the string literal cannot be converted to the `int` return value.

Since C++17, you can use `if constexpr` to tell the compiler that the condition is a compile time constant which allows it to only compile the needed branches:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>::value)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"foo is: "<<foo<int>()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you need a solution in earlier standards, you'll have to use template specialization like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

//general template
template <typename T>
T foo();

//specialization for int
template <>
int foo<int>()
{
    return 2;
}

//specialization for string
template <>
string foo<string>()
{
    return "apple";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"foo is: "<<foo<int>()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks like I don't have the C++17 one: `error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’`, can you explain the other approach as well?

Comment: Did you add `--std=c++17` to your compiler command?
Anyway I'll edit the answer with the other version.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that means we have to write actions/logics for that particulate `typename` in their corresponding function? What if most of the function body is same for both?

Comment: Yes you'll need to separate the implementations for each type. If you have a lot of common code, it may be best to factor-out only the specific parts into their own functions and call those from the general implementation.

Comment: Great, one last thing, can you point out what is going wrong in my attempted code I updated just now?

Comment: The way you wrote it, `U` is also a type but you want it to be a value. That is possible for some types but not all. You could pass it as a regular parameter but now it no longer is fully compile-time: https://godbolt.org/z/7xv99z1hG
Which way you do it will depend on you specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Template instantiations must be valid on all branches, which yours aren't. What I mean by that is this is how the functions generated by your template look like:

```
int foo<int>()
{
    if(true)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(false)
    {
        return "apple"; // error
    }
}

std::string foo<std::string>()
{
    if(false)
    {
        return 2; // error
    }
    if(true)
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}
```

Since C++17 you can use constexpr if to solve this:

```
template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to C++17's constexpr-if if you are in earlier language versions is tag dispatch:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

template <typename T> struct Tag {};

int f_impl(Tag<int>) { return 2; }
std::string f_impl(Tag<std::string>) { return "apple"; }

} // namespace detail

template <typename T> T foo() { return detail::f_impl(detail::Tag<T>{}); }

int main() {
  std::cout << "foo is: " << foo<int>() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For this simple example specializations will do, but tag dispatch can be useful for more complex "if-else-dispatch" logic.